# How to run gdb-many-windows in new frame?

Tags: emacs, gdb

I know I can open a new frame and <kbd>M+x</kbd>`gdb`. But just doing <kbd>M+x</kbd>`gdb` and having `gdb` executed in a new frame would be much better.

`gdb-many-windows` destroy original windows layout when I run it and it can not restore the layout when I kill it. So I want to run it in a new frame and close that frame.

**Update:** I use `(setq gdb-many-windows t)`. If I invoke `gdb`, it uses the `gdb-many-windows` layout automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple function to call `gdb` with many windows in a newly created frame:

```lisp
(defun my-gdb-other-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (select-frame (make-frame))
  (call-interactively 'gdb))
```

---

Another way I use to solve the window layout problem with `gdb-many-windows` is to save the different windows configurations to registers. FWIW, here is my workflow:

1. <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (save window configuration to register `a`)
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`gdb`<kbd>RET</kbd>
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`gdb-many-windows`<kbd>RET</kbd>
4. <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (save the new window configuration to register `b`)

Afterwards, I can jump from one window layout to the other using <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

Comment: This is a bit complex... If (setq gdb-many-windows t), my-gdb-other-frame fail.  Thank you all the same

Comment: No error. If (setq gdb-many-windows t), the gdb-many-windows layout is  still opened in the old frame and a gud buffer is opened in new frame.

Comment: OK. I think I fixed this in a new version of the function. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, it almost work...The first time, when I invoke my-gdb-other-frame, it works. Then I close gud, invoke it again, it does not work. Then I close it, invoke it again, it works..... There is something wrong here. Please check it again. Many thanks :-)

Comment: I think there was an interaction between this snippet and my `init.el` that made this work with my configuration. I edited the post to propose a much simpler version which should work in all cases (I tested it using `emacs -q` so it is relatively safe this time)